# Having Issue on Configuring Windows Server 2016 Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

Logged in to windows Server 2016 as an administrator, I have enable **Active Directory Domain Services** on Windows Server 2016 by adding role. The **Active Directory Users and Computers** is listing under `Control Panel | Administrative Tools` as shown in following image but when I click on that, I am getting following message

> To manage users and groups on this computers use Local Users and Groups.
> To manage users, groups and computers in a domain, log on as a user with domain administration right.

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new Active Directory forest, or standing up a domain controller to add to an existing forest/domain?

Answer (score 0):

•   You are encountering this error because ‘Active Directory Domain Services’ role surely has been installed on the Windows Server 2016 server, but it has not been yet promoted to ‘Domain Controller’. By promoting the server to DC and initializing its authority over the DNS zones hosted on this Server or any other server on which DNS role is installed, you would grant the user ID which you configure while promoting to DC as the default Domain and Schema Administrator. And then by logging in with this ID, you will be able to access the various service management consoles of Active Directory.

Thus, kindly promote the Server to the level of Domain Controller in your environment and then try logging in to the Server with that ID. You should be able to access the features of Active Directory. For promoting the Server to DC, please refer to the documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/deploy/install-active-directory-domain-services--level-100-#BKMK_GUI